# Creating a function that converts functions of one type to another

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

For some fancy reflection stuff, I've got a function of type Func and need to pass it into a function that accepts type Func where T is not known until run time.  For example:

```
public bool MyOperation(Func<string,bool> op) {
  return _myValues.Any(op);
}

public static bool InvokeOperationMethod(MethodInfo info, object obj,Func<object,bool> opAsObject)
{
   info.Invoke(obj, opAsObject);
}
```

The issue is that since I've got a lambda of a weaker type, I can't pass it as an argument of a stronger type.  So I tried to make a helper that will create a function that converts a lambda of a weaker type into a stronger type.  For example, I could call

```
var converter = CreateConverter(typeof(string));
Func<object,bool> asObject = o => o.ToString() == "a string"; //Dump example
Func<string,bool> asString = (Func<string,bool>)converter(asObject);
Assert.IsTrue(asInt("a string"));
```

Of course in the actual code this the destination type is not known until run time, and the actual predicate is not some trivial test.

This is my attempt:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a predicate of Func<object,bool> to
/// Func<Type,bool> of the given type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="destType">Type of the dest.</param>
/// <param name="predicate">The predicate.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static TransformPredicate CreateConverter(Type destType)
{
    // This essentially creates the following lambda, but uses destType instead of T
    // private static Func<Func<object, bool>, Func<T, bool>> Transform<T>()
    // { 
    //     return (Func<object,bool> input) => ((T x) => input(x));
    // }
    var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Func<object, bool>), "input");

    var x = Expression.Parameter(destType, "x");
    var convert = Expression.Convert(x, typeof(object));
    var callInputOnX = Expression.Invoke(input, convert);
    var body2 = Expression.Lambda(callInputOnX, x);
    var body1 = Expression.Lambda(typeof(TransformPredicate),body2, input);
    return (TransformPredicate) body1.Compile();
}

public delegate object TransformPredicate(Func<object,bool> weak);
```

This actually works just fine, except that it runs really slowly since it's implicitly invoking CreateDelegate on each invocation. So I tried to call CreateDelegate myself by adding:

```
var destFunc = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(destType, typeof(bool));
var endType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<object, bool>), destFunc);
return (TransformPredicate)compiled.Method.CreateDelegate(endType);
```

This results in an error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Derived classes must provide and implementation.

Any ideas how I can call CreateDelegate myself?

Comment: This might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you just call `asObject("a string")`? I think it's matters how exactly are you going to use the result, so it would help if you showed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, as long long as the target type is a reference type, you don't have to do anything. The type parameter `T` in `Func<T, TResult>` is *contravariant*, which means you can do the cast directly. Because of this, the following code works fine:

```
Func<object,bool> asObject = o => o.ToString() == "a string";
Func<string,bool> asString = (Func<string,bool>)asObject;
asString("a string");
```

**EDIT:** It's not the compiler doing the conversion, it's the CLR that understands that `Func<object, bool>` can be safely casted to `Func<string, bool>`. So, the following code will work just fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        InvokeOperationMethod(
            typeof(Program).GetMethod("MyOperation"),
            new Program(), o => o.ToString() == "42");
    }

    public bool MyOperation(Func<string, bool> op)
    {
        return op("43");
    }

    public static bool InvokeOperationMethod(
        MethodInfo info, object obj, Func<object, bool> opAsObject)
    {
        return (bool)info.Invoke(obj, new object[] { opAsObject });
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** If you need this to work for value types too, you will need to box the parameter somehow. The boxing itself is simple:

```
private static Func<T, bool> BoxParameter<T>(Func<object, bool> op)
{
    return x => op(x);
}
```

But then you need to invoke it, and since you don't know `T` at compile time, you need to use reflection for that. Something like:

```
public static bool InvokeOperationMethod(
    MethodInfo method, object obj, Func<object, bool> opAsObject)
{
    var targetType = method.GetParameters()
                           .Single()
                           .ParameterType
                           .GetGenericArguments()[0];

    object opAsT;
    if (targetType.IsValueType)
    {
        opAsT =
            typeof(Program).GetMethod("BoxParameter",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                           .MakeGenericMethod(targetType)
                           .Invoke(null, new object[] {opAsObject});
    }
    else
    {
        opAsT = opAsObject;
    }

    return (bool)method.Invoke(obj, new[] { opAsT });
}
```

Comment: I've tried to clarify what I need this to happen in reflection, and why I need to actually make a converter rather than depend on the compiler to do the casting for me.

Comment: You're right. I forgot the reason I needed this is that sometimes the target type is not by ref. Any ideas how to do it there? I've always been confused about the relationship between object and by ref types, since I can do: object o = 1; o.Dump();