# CreateDelegate Derived classes must provide an implementation

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates, linq-expressions

When calling creating a compiled expressiong I'm trying to call CreateDelegate on the resultant compiled delegate, but am geeting a NotSupportedException, with the explanation being: Derived classes must provide an implementation. How do I create the delegate for a compiled method?

```
public delegate int AddOne(int input);

void Main()
{
    var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
    var add = Expression.Add(input,Expression.Constant(1));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(AddOne),add,input);
    var compiled = (AddOne)lambda.Compile();
    compiled.Method.CreateDelegate(typeof(AddOne));
}
```

Comment: It is still actual. I also need to get MethodInfo of compiled delegate, save it in my strucutres and then "re-cast" MethodInfo to delegate again. This code should work but it doesnt' and nature of ''Derived classes must provide an implementation' error is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `CreateDelegate`. Casting the result from `lambda.Compile` to `AddOne` was all you needed.

Observe:

```
public delegate int AddOne(int input);

public int Test(AddOne f)
{
   return f(1);
}

void Main()
{
    var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
    var add = Expression.Add(input,Expression.Constant(1));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(AddOne),add,input);
    var compiled = (AddOne)lambda.Compile();
    Console.WriteLine(Test(compiled)); // 2
}
```

You can successfully call the `Test` method, which accepts a delegate of type `AddOne`.

Comment: So I've done that, and it works fine. The problem is it's super slow. In performance testing 93% of the time of invoking the function is spent in System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type,Object). Since I call this function many times inside a tight loop, I'm thinking that if I can call this myself once it won't need to call it each time.

Comment: @heneryville As long as you're only calling `Compile` once, it shouldn't take that long. I tried calling `Test(compiled)` in a `for`-loop and only got a noticeable slow down (~0.466 sec) at 100000000 iterations.

Comment: @heneryville I don't see anything about the performance in your question. Any reason not to *accept* if it works fine?

Comment: @heneryville I assume your real code is much different, you just dumbed it down for the question. Maybe you can include more detail about what you are actually doing and someone can suggest an alternative with better performance? Also, what type of performance are we talking about (93% of how many units?)

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Well, yes. I actually have a another post for the greater question, but I was so interested in CreateDelegate, I made this question to focus on it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016898/creating-a-function-that-converts-functions-of-one-type-to-another

Comment: @p.s.w.g You're right. On a stripped down test example, I was unable to reproduce and difference in speed.